# Laravel attach links in email that can redirect users to a localhost project

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-mail

wanted to ask a question. I have a localhost project and users are accessing the website using their own computer and my project ip address.

And I have a mail.blade.php which will help me send emails to users and I want to redirect them to my application by providing an anchor link or button in the email. Here is how I put the link, I use

```
<a href="{{ url('10.xx.xx.xx:8000') }}">...</a>
```

However, when user click the link, it will open a tab with url localhost/localhost/10.xx.xx.xx:8000 and show website no response error. May I know how can I get rid of the localhost/localhost prefix and only bring users to 10.xx.xx.xx:8000 ??

Below is a screenshot of my mail.blade.php:
[image]

Comment: use `<a href="10.xx.xx.xx:8000">...</a>` as it is a direct url no need to use `url()` helper

Comment: @KamleshPaul if I do so then the link will become unclickable

Comment: then put like `<a href="http://10.xx.xx.xx:8000">...</a>` put `https://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `url()` helper and use like `<a href="http://10.xx.xx.xx:8000">...</a>`

add `https://`

as a valid url start with `http`. or `https`